# React-Paginate is not clickable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I have been trying to use React-paginate library for pagination, however, the buttons formed by it is not clickable,i don't understand what i am doing wrong
And there are no example given, or no question asked

What would be the correct way of using this pagination

Here is the code of my App.js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from '../src/components/navbar/navbar'
import SearchIt from '../src/components/searchField/search'
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container'
import Card from '../src/components/cards/cards'
import Axios from 'axios'
import Pagination from '../src/components/pagination/paginating'

class App extends Component {
  state={
    fetchedData:[]
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    Axios.get('http://localhost:3000/1').then((responseData)=>{
      //console.log(responseData.data)
      this.setState({fetchedData:responseData.data})
    }).catch((err)=>{
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
  handlePageClicked = data => {
    let selected = data.selected;
    console.log(selected)    
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar/>
        <Container> 
          <SearchIt/>
          <Card data={this.state.fetchedData}/>
          <Pagination handlePageClick={this.handlePageClicked}/>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );

  }
}

export default App;
```

And here is the code for paginating.js

```
   import React,{Component} from 'react'
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';
import './paginateStyle.css'


 const page = (props)=>{
     return(

      <ReactPaginate
          previousLabel={'previous'}
          nextLabel={'next'}
          breakLabel={'...'}
          breakClassName={'break-me'}
          pageCount={10}
          marginPagesDisplayed={2}
          pageRangeDisplayed={5}
          onPageChange={props.handlePageClick}
          containerClassName={'pagination'}
          subContainerClassName={'pages pagination'}
          activeClassName={'active'}
        />

     )
 }

 export default page
```

These button are not clickable
[image: this buttons]

Comment: I did a quick sample using react-paginate and everything seems fine.
Did you verify console in case you are seeing any issues?
Also, I see you are just logging to console when a pagenumber is clicked. Did you miss something here?

Comment: Yes, i do missed, a ui component with higher z index was over them and was not visible :-( I wasted 6 hours of a fruitful day

Comment: ohh.. kk.. atleast you identified it..

Comment: Yahhh, thanks for taking the effort to recreate it, if you do ans, will mark it correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a quick sample and it worked.

```
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';

const Pagination = (props) => {
return (

<ReactPaginate
  previousLabel={'previous'}
  nextLabel={'next'}
  breakLabel={'...'}
  breakClassName={'break-me'}
  pageCount={10}
  marginPagesDisplayed={2}
  pageRangeDisplayed={5}
  onPageChange={props.handlePageClick}
  containerClassName={'pagination'}
  subContainerClassName={'pages pagination'}
  activeClassName={'active'}
  />

 )
}


class App extends Component {
 state = {
  selectedPage: 0
 }

handlePageClicked = data => {
  let selected = data.selected;
  this.setState({
    selectedPage: selected
  })
  console.log(selected)
};

render() {

return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <div>You selected:  {this.state.selectedPage}</div>

    <div className="App">
      <Pagination handlePageClick={this.handlePageClicked} />
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
 );

 }
}
```

There could be something in paginateStyle.css which is making the Pagination not work properly or some other CSS in your application.

EDIT:
From comments, a ui component with higher z index was over them and was not visible/clickable

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I didn't realize I could only click on the numbers. The containers were not clickable.

Instead of styling the `a` element I had styled the `li`. "Transferring" the styling to the `a` element solved my problem.